# The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values - even with `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *` in NGINX

Tags: nginx, cors

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values
>   'http://127.0.0.1:8888, *', but only one is allowed. Have the server
>   send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves
>   your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource
>   with CORS disabled.

This is the error the browser client application gets when accessing an NGINX backend server.

I have added this code

```
server { 
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    server_name ~. "";
    location / {   
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://keepalive-upstream; 
        # adding this causes browser CORS issue
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }
}
```

Also replaced the `*` with `$host` but neither works.

Comment: Did you restart nginx after chancing the values?

Comment: Yes I did restart, `sudo nginx -s reload`